# Padding not applied to ul

Tags: html, css, padding

i really don`t know whats going on here.

I have the following HTML syntax

```
<div class="album_column>
  ...
    <ul>
     ...
    </ul>
  ...
</div>
```

And the following css:

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.album_column ul {
  display: block;
  padding: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

But for some reason, the padding of `.album_column ul` isn't applied to the ul (but all other arguments i can think of are, like margin, color, whatsoever)

You can see the behavior in the following screenshot:
[image: Padding not applied]
any input appreciated :) thanks a lot guys!

edit: additional screenshot:
[image: padding manipulated]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto` is [not a valid](http://www.cssbasics.com/chapter_8_css_padding.html) value for `padding` property, the only thing you can do is take out `padding: 0;`

Comment: okay, good to know.
But if i manipulate the property padding for the ul element within my firebug extension from 0 to auto, i achieved that the list is centered within the div element.

Comment: @fighter-ii Please give me a code snippet ( codepen.io, plnkr, jsfiddle etc.)

Comment: i added an additional screenshot, just to show you, that padding:auto is doing something (thats why i thougt it woukd work)
But i accept your answer, that this is not a valid property and i have to center it in an other way

Comment: @fighter-ii I need a code of your page and then I'll help you (use codepen, jsfiddle, plnkr etc)

Comment: @fighter-ii `padding:auto` overwrites the `padding:0` in `ul` but as it is an invalid value you get the default value in `ul` (most browser set a `padding-left`). You can use `initial` value to get the default with a valid CSS

Comment: yeah: and the initial value is 0, right?
Strangely my firefox / firebug behave differently.
If i use `padding: 0` or `padding: initial` the list is aligned left, no padding. If i disable the css value completly (or delete it from my css), the list has a padding of `40` to the left.

@ArtemSolovev http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKGRVY here is a reduced part of my code.

Comment: sorry I said wrong, the `initial` value doesn't reset the `ul` value, set the default value of the property, in this case as you say is 0

Answer (score 1):

The padding:auto is an invalid property value, thats why t is not applying, you can either give the padding value in em,px or %.

Thanks
Satya

Answer (score 0):

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxvfp4bh/)

```
<div>
<div class="album_column">
<ul>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
</div>

.album_column ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Do not using padding auto. it is an invalid property.